# Single click or double click on table row in a web app

Tags: usability, user-behavior, web-app, design-patterns

we currently have a interaction with table rows that allow for double click to open. If you single-click, then it highlights the table row; however, there is no additional option to multi-select rows or anything like that. Is it intuitive enough for someone to know to double click the row in order to open it? There is a link on the first table-cell that opens the object. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double-click action is a norm for desktop apps. First click to select, second to launch. For those who grew up using a desktop device, they are familiar with such action and will instinctively double click any icons, button etc.

However it's less commonly used in web apps and even lesser for mobile apps. You have to consider the millennials, some of them who might grew up using tablets and mobile devices only.

I would encourage you to explore other alternatives such as using an icon or button to replace a double click action.